# How to tell what line of code created new thread (gdb)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, gdb

I'm attempting to debug a rather complicated program that is seg faulting. I've just learned about gdb and am trying to use it to find the problem. Currently, it shows

```
[New Thread 0x7fff4963700 (LWP 4768)]
[New Thread 0x7fff1faf700 (LWP 4769)]
[New Thread 0x7fff17ae700 (LWP 4768)]
```

very shortly after my program commences. That would be great if I had written multithreaded code, but I haven't. Is there a way to tell exactly what line of code is creating these new threads?

Answer (score 12):

Working on Linux, `catch syscall clone` should break on all threads (and possibly some processes) creation. Notice that it will break in the creator thread (=the new thread is yet to be started).

Since you get the full backtrace that leads to the `clone`, if you need to extract the new thread entry point you should do `up` until you reach the `pthread_create` (or similar library function) stack frame and take it from its parameters (you can also directly check the parameters to `clone`, but I fear that the address there will be of some pthread library stub).

Comment: What if a new thread was started from another, non-main thread? It did not work for me and my `qml` application. The only place where `gdb` paused was creating threads from main thread.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: last time I tried it worked the same.

Comment: Hm, for me it did not stop at `openmp` threads and `QtConcurrent::run`

Comment: Actually I tried it exactly with QtConcurrent::run and it worked, maybe the threads in the thread pool were already started? In that case it's normal that you don't see anything, there's no thread creation going on.

Comment: Okay, maybe it works for QtConcurrent::run but why did not it stop on `openmp` cloning then? You may see call stack above and it contains `clone` but gdb did not stop with `catch syscall clone`...

Comment: Same as before: did you add the `catch` before `run`? Because otherwise OpenMP may spin its workers before you have the occasion to add the `catch` (notice that I'm not familiar with OpenMP's inner workings, so I may be missing something).

Comment: Yes, of course I added `catch` before calling `run` and even specifying `file`. I've tried it 3 times already with fresh gdb run.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: later I'll try to check it on my machine, could you provide a sample source?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: I tried a simple example with OpenMP and I catch the `clone` without issues (see http://pastebin.com/0v7NpwtM) (both on my 4-core KUbuntu 14.04 laptop and on a 24-core CentOS server); is there anything "strange" in your configuration that may trigger the problem? What is your GDB version?

Answer (score 3):

Threads have their own call stack. The only thing you can see is the value on the bottom of the stack. Point the **thread id** in `t <thread id>` or `thread <thread id>` and get call stack using `bt` or `backtrace`. You may obtain thread ids during pausing execution of your application in `gdb` and running `info threads`.

For example, my gdb session look like (specially tried to make be more clear for you) this:

```
(gdb) t 23
[Switching to thread 23 (Thread 0x7fff8ffff700 (LWP 32334))]
#0  0x00007fffc0cb829e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffc0cb829e in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
#1  0x00007fffc0cb5bb0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1
#2  0x00007ffff52b10a5 in start_thread (arg=0x7fff8ffff700) at pthread_create.c:309
#3  0x00007ffff591a88d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

Here gdb says that first value of the call stack is somewhere in `libgomp.so` (**OpenMP** library). Next you can see `pthread_create.c` which is system-dependent method of starting thread.